# Why do I get different results in .NET4 compared to .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

When I have my project's target framework set to Framework 4.0 and run the following code:

```
 Assembly pAsm = Assembly.LoadFrom(aMagPath);
 foreach (Module m in pAsm.GetModules())
 {
    Type t = m.GetType("typeName"));
 }
```

typeName is a user defined type from a 3rd party dll.

t is null.

If I change the target type to Framework 3.5 t is not null.

I don't change anything else.  I just change the target framework and rerun the application.

Can anyone explain why this it happening?
is there some tool that will let me look into this more?

UPDATE:
I changed my code to the following.

```
Assembly pAsm = Assembly.LoadFrom(aMagPath);
Type t = pAsm.GetType(String.Format("GM.FCAT.{0}.{0}+FBlock+{1}Function+{2}CaseStream+{2}RepeatableParameterStream", FBlockName, pName, aParam.Name), false);
```

I still have the same problem.
t = null in version 4.0 and doesn't in version 3.5

I can't find the type when I load it into .net reflector.  so I guess it is not really there.

Comment: What is "m", and what's the type you're looking for?

Comment: What is m, and what is happening with the parentheses?

Comment: @ jon - i edited the question to anwser yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some framework types have moved across assemblies between versions, with an assembly binding redirection to make it *usually* invisible to clients. That *may* explain what's going on, but it's hard to say without knowing which assembly and type you're trying to find.

EDIT: Okay, now that we've got a bit more context...

That suggests the type really isn't in that module... It's possible that there was a bug in .NET 3.5 which looked in the parent assembly for the type name instead of just within the module.

Is there any reason why you *have* to look on a module-by-module basis, instead of just asking the assembly itself for the type?

Comment: the assembly is autogenerated by a third party toolkit as is the type.

Comment: @scott: Well, that suggests the type really isn't in that module... see my edit.

Comment: Hmm. So it only appears to be there in 3.5? thats interesting.  Any ideas on why that happens?

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that.  I'll try asking the assembly itself. Thanks.